# how to fill css file dynamically in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, database, styles

I am working on a asp.net mvc 5 project and I have a css style file in mvc project and it is possible to be changed with an image so I want to set an url("../images/aa.jpg"); from sqlserver now I dont know how to do this

```
.img-about{
    background: url("../images/aa.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
.img-sports{
    background: url("../images/aa.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
.img-gallery{
    background: url("../images/aa.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
.img-feature{
    background: url("../images/aa.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
.img-news{
    background: url("../images/aa.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
.img-contact{
    background: url("../images/aa.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can create some .cshtml that have internal styles/scripts:
[Dynamically generated Javascript and CSS in ASP.NET MVC using Razor Views](http://blog.pmunin.com/2013/04/dynamic-javascript-css-in-aspnet-mvc.html)

But the question is, **why?**
You can include the `url` in your `model` and use [`inline styles`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_howto_inline).
Also, if you always generate the css/js on the fly, you won't be able to take advantage of the `browser caching` and/or [`bundling and minification`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification).